# How to retrieve with vba the full list of built-In excel functions?

Tags: excel, vba, function, built-in

This is it. I am trying to get the list of built-in functions of Excel (not built-in functions of VBA) by using VBA.

I know how to retrieve UDFs and functions in non-protected XLA and XLL addins, but I can't find a way of getting the list of excel functions. Do you know how I could obtain that using VBA? I think it should be a way.

I would like to avoid using list of functions copied from some site (or ms help), because that would ask the user to check it, in a regular basis, to keep it updated, which is not an option.

BTW, the context of this is a kind of parser of excel formulas to vba, which I have almost finished; I only miss this.

Thank you!

Comment: Tx, but WorksheetFunctions (with 's' at the end) is not recognized by VBA, how should I use it? I get an "out of context" error in watch when in runtime and checking "Application.WorksheetFunctions(1).Name" or just "Application.WorksheetFunctions(1)"

Comment: @ExcelHero  How do we access members of a built-in VBA Class ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.   It only displays worksheet functions installed with **your version** of Excel.

1. Open the VBA window
2. Click *View* > *Object Browser*
3. Scroll down the *Classes* pane and click on *WorksheetFunction*
4. The list of functions will be displayed in the *Members* pane

[image]

Another open issue is how to transfer the displayed list of members into a worksheet column.